# Reflection.Emit parameters passing

Tags: c#, wcf, reflection.emit

I want to create an autogenerated proxy for WCF service that allows me to avoid manual creation of service proxies.

Using reflection emit, I've created the full cycle of dynamic class generation (from assembly to methods) and code of my method generation looks like so:

```
        bool isVoid;

        if ((isVoid = (methodInfo.ReturnType != typeof(void))))
            generator.DeclareLocal(methodInfo.ReturnType);

        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        var channelProperty = baseType.GetMethod(ChannelPropertyGetName, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.GetProperty);

        generator.EmitCall(OpCodes.Call, channelProperty, null);

        for (short index = 0; index < parameters.Count(); index++)
            generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg, (index + 1));

        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, methodInfo);

        if (isVoid)
        {
            generator.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_0);
            generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_0);
        }

        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
```

I also have a service and appropriate service contract looks like so:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface INamingService
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Resolve a name
    /// </summary>
    [OperationContract(Name = "GetName")]
    string GetName(string name);

}
```

but when I'm trying to retrieve value from this service by specified name (not null), I see that the parameter which comes up from client call is null. Thus, as far as I understand, I made a mistake in Emit and parameter doesn't passed.

Could anyone advise to me, how to resolve this issue?

Comment: My advice would be to write the code you desire in C#, compile it and compare the generated IL with what you are emitting for the task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a few minor points:

1. `isVoid` seems like a poor name since it indicates that the method *does not* return void.
2. Your use of a local seems unnecessary - you are simply storing to it and then immediately reloading that value.
3. I don't understand why you're using `EmitCall` for the property getter; you should almost certainly be using `Emit` instead (see [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.ilgenerator.emitcall.aspx)).

However, I don't see why you think that the problem is with your IL generation; to me it sounds more likely that you are either

1. Declaring your dynamic method incorrectly, or
2. Mis-wiring the proxy somehow.

Comment: I've taken your comments into account, thank you.
Nevertheless, as you said, the solution laid in the orthogonal place - I had incorrectly defined binding. Thank you for advice